# Making a react prop strict type to a specific component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How would I go about making a prop strict type to a specific component.

I have a component called ControlPanel which has an interface of ControlPanelProps
I also have a provider that has a function called showComponent. I want that function to only allow when called to be passed a prop of component ControlPanel

I thought type AllowedComponentTypes = ReactElement
Would do the trick but it apperas I can pass it any react component.
So if ControlPanelProps has no affect on this what does.

Example:

```
  type AllowedComponentTypes = ReactElement<ControlPanelProps>

  const showComponent = (content: AllowedComponentTypes) => {
      setContent(content)

  }
```

If this is not achievable in typescript what is a better way to do this to pass dynamic components to a function and have it type safe so a user can't pass unwanted components.